# Limit privileges of a systemd service to a minimum

Tags: security, systemd, privileges, sandbox

I am writing a systemd service file for [fai-monitor (8)](https://fai-project.org/doc/man/fai-monitor.html). This daemon listens on a single port, receives TCP connections, and writes a single log file with interesting information.

To reduce the attack surface on the system, the service should be run with the least privileges possible. Following the advice on [options for hardening systemd service units](https://gist.github.com/ageis/f5595e59b1cddb1513d1b425a323db04), I came up with this service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=FAI Monitor Daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fai-monitor -l /run/fai-monitor/fai-monitor.log
DynamicUser=true
RuntimeDirectory=fai-monitor
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755

MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateUsers=true
ProtectHome=true

ProtectSystem=strict
PrivateDevices=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectControlGroups=true

RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET AF_INET6
RestrictRealtime=true

TasksMax=16
MemoryHigh=10M

SystemCallFilter=~@mount @debug @privileged
```

While this seems to be quite restrictive, the service file is relatively verbose.

Are there any other means to restrict a service to the least possible set of privileges? In particular, something like `RestrictEverything=true` would be interesting with subsequent whitelisting of allowed ressources.